# Baby Bjorn and heat rashes

Tags: infant, transport

Has anybody else had any trouble using the baby bjorn in regards to heat rashes? Both myself and my little one are appropriately dressed for the weather, but when I put him into the carrier facing me, he always gets red bumps on his belly. I'm not sure if dressing him less is the answer. For people with baby bjorns out there, do you dress your little one less in anticipation of body heat?

Answer (score 1):

I used the baby bjorn carrier with my daughter and never had a problem.  I will say that in the summer time I just put her in a short sleeve onesie and that was it.  All babies are different though.  Your baby maybe a little bit bigger than my daughter was, when I used it and maybe his tummy rubs more on the the carrier while you're walking, causing friction on his tummy.

I would say to just try some different things like less clothing and see if that helps.  Maybe some talc free powder on his tummy before hand to help in keeping that area dry.

Also on colder days maybe try putting a jacket on him, that is easy to take off when you get inside, so that he stays warm outside in the cold, but you can take it off indoors easily.  Your body heat through the carrier should keep him pretty warm indoors.